# Indexing a unmapped/dynamically mapped document with a geopoint in elasticsearch NEST client

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

This is my first question on this website so i will try to ask the question correct.

while working with the elasticsearch nest client i use bulk indexing to store my data. All the data can be indexed with the help of a `Dictionary<string, object>`.
The company i work for insists on dynamic mapping, which means i am not allowed to declare the variables that go to the nodes.

```
Dictionary <string, object> document_value= new Dictionary<string, object>();
Bulkcontainer.Index<object>(i => i.Index(index_name).Type(_type).Id(_id).Document(document_value));
```

This wasnt a problem until the use of GEO points.
if these arent indexed as geopoints they will not be searchable, when placed in the dictonary they will default to string. i am not able to override them.
the data for geopoint are given to the code in the form of another dictonary called geofields.

```
PointGeoShape coord = new PointGeoShape();
    Dictionary<string, PointGeoShape> geovalue = new Dictionary<string, PointGeoShape>();
    if (geofields!= null)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> geo in geofields)
        {
            string veldnaam = geo.Key.ToUpper();
            string temp = geo.Value.ToString();
            if (temp != "")
            {
                string[] array = temp.Split(new char[] { ',' }, 2);
                List<double> list = new List<double>();
                list.Add(double.Parse(array[0]));//lon
                list.Add(double.Parse(array[1]));//lat
                IEnumerable<double> latlon = list;
                coord.Coordinates = latlon;
                document_value.Add(veldnaam, coord);
            }
        }
     }
```

any help to clarify my problem will be appreciated

---

i changed the index type to

```
public class ES_DATA_GEO
{
public Dictionary<string, object> Data { get; set; }
[ElasticProperty(Type = Nest.FieldType.GeoShape)]
public GeoShape Locatiecoord { get; set; }
}
```

but now when i execute the query it still doesnt register Locatiecoord as Geo field

```
Failed to find geo_shape field [locatiecoord]];
```

again any help is appreciated

Comment: Hi Roy, I have one similar one, in case you have solved it, do let me know, I have placed my question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33579086/unable-to-insert-dynamic-object-to-elastic-search-using-nest

Comment: Hi @Roy! Did you manage to solve it in the end? If yes, how? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Florin, Its been years, but never did find a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

According the docs, geo points cannot be automatically detected with dynamic mapping. See [Geo Points](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/geopoints.html)

Comment: Hi, @jrao77! Still, is there a workaround to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you create your index like this:

```
var created = client.CreateIndex("MyIndexName", 
    c => c.AddMapping<dynamic>(m => m.Type("_default_").
    DynamicTemplates(t => t.Add(f => f.Name("shape_fields")
    .Match("MyShapeFieldName").Mapping(ma => ma.GeoPoint(s => 
    s.IndexGeoHash().IndexLatLon()))))
```

Then your initial approach of indexing the dictionary directly will work assuming you have an entry in your dictionary with the key "MyShapeFieldName" which has a Coordinate value. You can probably change my sample to match based on type (Coordinate) rather than name ("MyShapeFieldName"), but I have not tested that.